# Delphi webbrowser - нажать

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Есть компонент `Webbrowser`, как можно реализовать клик ЛКМ по этому компоненту,
т.е. например я нажимаю на `Button1` и происходит действие где проходит левый щелчек мыши по определенным координатам (координаты относительно компонента, а не экрана) можно ли такое сделать?
я приблизительно наткнулся на такое:

```
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTDOWN,x,y,0,0);
Mouse_Event(MOUSEEVENTF_LEFTUP,x,y,0,0);
```

но тут относительно экрана или того элемента на который ты кликаешь я так и не понял, а мне хотелось бы от в компонент...

Answer (score 1):

```
((WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocumnt).all as IHTMLElementCollection).item(index).click
```

Если нужно, могу скинуть свои наработки для поиска элементов по имени, или другим параметрам.

Comment: было бы неплохо глянуть примеры. есть ссылка?

Comment: наработки: http://www.fayloobmennik.net/2644771 или http://paste.ubuntu.com/1702152/

краткий пример: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1702257/

пример на основе старого (недоделанного) проекта: http://paste.ubuntu.com/1702284/

Answer (score 0):

Тут относительно экрана.

Если нужно относительно компонента, то рассчитывайте исходя из **left, top** формы, и **left, top** компонента на форме.